# Can anyone help me with translation of this struct to delphi record?

Tags: c++, delphi, struct

I need help to transcribe a struct that has another nested struct to Delphi. Below is a struct:

```
#define CHANNEL_TAG_LENGTH 17
struct stChannelInfo
 {
  char ChannelTag[CHANNEL_TAG_LENGTH];  // Tag (máx 16 caracteres)
  char ChannelEnabled;  // Habilitado se diferente de "0"
 };

// Structure with information about channels
struct stChannel
 {
  int ChannelNumber;  // Número de canais no buffer
  struct stChannelInfo *ChannelInfo;  // Buffer com informações dos canais
 };
```

In Borland C + + 6, the example uses the following code to read the value of ChannelTag:

```
 stChannels = this->deviceInterface->LookForAvailableChannels(EdDirectorySource->Text.c_str(), iSn, dateTimeStart, dateTimeEnd);
 for(int i = 0; i < stChannels.ChannelNumber; i++)
 {
  CLbChannels->Items->Add(stChannels.ChannelInfo[i].ChannelTag);  // Add to list the values found
 }
```

I wish I could do the same in Delphi. How should I transcribe structs?

Thanks and sorry because English is not my native language

**EDIT**

I was wrong not to post what I had done on Delphi. Follow my attempt:

```
// record who receive the values 
type stChannelInfo = record
    ChannelTag : string[16];    
    ChannelEnabled : char ; 
end;

type stChannel = record
    ChannelNumber:integer;  // Númber of buffer channels
    ChannelInfo : ^stChannelInfo ;
end;
```

And so i tried to read :

```
 Var DadosCanais : stChannel;  // defined in var section of procedure onclick Button.

 DadosCanais:=LookForAvailableChannels (Pwidechar(dirroot) , sn , datepickerinicial.DateTime,datepickerfinal.DateTime);
 for i := 0 to (DadosCanais.ChannelNumber-1) do  
  begin  
   Showmessage(String(DadosCanais.ChannelInfo^.ChannelTag));
   inc(DadosCanais.ChannelInfo);
  end;
```

I get the record, but I can not correctly read ​​ChannelTag values. It seems that the size is incorrect, because the strings is truncated and always lose the first character of the name.

Maybe this clarify a little the question. Thanks again

**SOLUTION**

Following advice from Remy , i do this :

```
 sn:=strtoint(lstdirMaquinas.Items[lstdirMaquinas.Itemindex]);
 Dadoscanais := LookForAvailableChannels(PChar(dirroot) , sn , datepickerinicial.DateTime,datepickerfinal.DateTime);
 for i:=0 to DadosCanais.ChannelNumber-1 do
  begin
    ListboxChannel.Items.add(String(DadosCanais.ChannelInfo[i].ChannelTag));
  end;
```

For now this resolves my problem. Thanks all.

Comment: Sorry, but this site is not for others to do your work for you. You should at least include what you've tried and where it fails. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Pascal_and_C

Comment: That's actually not completely correct (note that the second part of the second struct is a pointer to an array of channel infos!)

Comment: You should post what did you try and which problem(s) are you having.

Comment: I guess that first of all you need to show us some evidence of what you know and what you don't know. For all we can tell you might not know how to declare a record or an array in Delphi. Which would seem to be quite likely because a simpler struct than this there could not be.

Comment: Sorry all , first time i post here. I will update my post now to show what i did.

Comment: +1 thanks for listening and improving the post. Good for you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```pascal
{$POINTERMATH ON}

Type
  PstChannelInfo = ^stChannelInfo;
  stChannelInfo = record
    ChannelTag: array[0..CHANNEL_TAG_LENGTH-1] of AnsiChar;  // Tag (máx 16 caracteres)
    ChannelEnabled: AnsiChar;  // Habilitado se diferente de "0"
  end;

  // Structure with information about channels
  stChannel = record
    ChannelNumber: Integer;  // Número de canais no buffer
    ChannelInfo: PstChannelInfo;  // Buffer com informações dos canais
  end;
```

```pascal
stChannels := Self.deviceInterface.LookForAvailableChannels(PChar(EdDirectorySource.Text), iSn, dateTimeStart, dateTimeEnd);
for i := 0 to stChannels.ChannelNumber-1 do begin
  CLbChannels.Items.Add(stChannels.ChannelInfo[i].ChannelTag);  // Add to list the values found
end;
```

Alternatively:

```pascal
Type
  PstChannelInfo = ^stChannelInfo;
  stChannelInfo = record
    ChannelTag: array[0..CHANNEL_TAG_LENGTH-1] of AnsiChar;  // Tag (máx 16 caracteres)
    ChannelEnabled: AnsiChar;  // Habilitado se diferente de "0"
  end;

  // Structure with information about channels
  stChannel = record
    ChannelNumber: Integer;  // Número de canais no buffer
    ChannelInfo: PstChannelInfo;  // Buffer com informações dos canais
  end;

  PstChannelInfoList = ^TstChannelInfoList;
  TstChannelInfoList = [0..(MaxInt div SizeOf(stChannelInfo))-1] of stChannelInfo;
```

```pascal
stChannels := Self.deviceInterface.LookForAvailableChannels(PChar(EdDirectorySource.Text), iSn, dateTimeStart, dateTimeEnd);
for i := 0 to stChannels.ChannelNumber-1 do begin
  CLbChannels.Items.Add(PstChannelInfoList(stChannels.ChannelInfo)^[i].ChannelTag);  // Add to list the values found
end;
```

Comment: Great ! Works like a charm ... i will post my code to everyone who needs help too. If i made some mistake please point me the error.  
I used the first idea , because the second tells me that TstChannelInfoList have a 2 GB of size and not compile.

Comment: `TstChannelInfoList = array[0..(MaxInt div SizeOf(stChannelInfo))-1] of stChannelInfo;`