# Another issue using structs and parameters of routines

Tags: delphi, struct

Earlier I had [problems in converting C/C++ structs to Delphi records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24513631/) and was helped. Fortunately the problem with struct ended but advancing further in the project I came across another problem.
I'll repeat the following struct only to improve the understanding of the issue:

```cpp
#define CHANNEL_TAG_LENGTH 17
struct stChannelInfo
{
    char ChannelTag[CHANNEL_TAG_LENGTH];    // Tag (máx 16 caracteres)
    char ChannelEnabled;    // Habilitado se diferente de "0"
};

// Structure with information about channels
struct stChannel
{
    int ChannelNumber;  // Número de canais no buffer
    struct stChannelInfo *ChannelInfo;  // Buffer com informações dos canais
};
```

In Delphi, I used this code with sucess to access member values:

```pascal
{$POINTERMATH ON}

Type
  PstChannelInfo = ^stChannelInfo;
  stChannelInfo = record
    ChannelTag: array[0..CHANNEL_TAG_LENGTH-1] of AnsiChar;  // Tag (máx 16 caracteres)
    ChannelEnabled: AnsiChar;  // Habilitado se diferente de "0"
  end;

// Structure with information about channels
Type
  PstChannel = ^stChannel;
  stChannel = record
    ChannelNumber: Integer;  // Número de canais no buffer
    ChannelInfo: PstChannelInfo;  // Buffer com informações dos canais
  end;

var
  DadosCanais: stChannel;
```

But now I have another problem, which is to use this DLL function:

```
char GatherData ( const struct stChannel channelBuffer, int blockIndex);
```

Following is a description of use of the DLL:

```
char GatherData ( const struct stChannel channelBuffer, int blockIndex)

Gets the equipment data from the data base, in the interval specified in the last call of "LookForAvailableChannels".  

Version: 1.00  

Parameters:  
channelBuffer                 inform in the structure which are the desired channels.
blockIndex                    inform the desired data block index.

Returns:
char Returns "0" in case of error and "1" if everything is OK.
```

The struct is populated by calling the `LookForAvailableChannels()` routine done in the previous row. I see the values ​​in `DadosCanais` normally.

So, I have defined `GatherData` in Delphi:

```pascal
function GatherData(ChannelBuffer : stChannel ; blockindex:integer):char ; stdcall; external 'Reader.dll';
```

And use like:

```pascal
GatherData(Dadoscanais,0)
```

And ... the function returns only `'0'` indicating that the function don't work. I don't know what to do now.

Can someone explain to me what should be done in Delphi to use this function?

Kindly someone could also point me some study material on this subject, so I could better understand what's happening

**EDIT1**
I changed my definition as Remy said , and now i receive "0" in return.
Looking in the source writen in Borland 6 C++ Builder , i saw this piece of code :

```cpp
iBlock = 1;
 if(this->deviceInterface->GatherData(*this->stChannels, iBlock)){
```

I wrote like this :

```
iBlock:=1;
 if ( GatherData(DadosCanais,1) = 1 ) then
```

**SOLUTION**

I researched more and found that beyond the question of type conversion, the dll was buggy. So Remy answer was right.

Comment: Study material: http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-convert.html ("Pitfalls of converting") which deals with lots of issues with respect to the conversion between C headers and Delphi.

Comment: Thank you Rudy. I will study the material.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your declaration of `GatherData()` is wrong.  Use this instead:

```
function GatherData(const channelBuffer: stChannel; blockIndex: Integer): AnsiChar; stdcall; external 'Reader.dll';
```

Or:

```
function GatherData(const channelBuffer: stChannel; blockIndex: Integer): AnsiChar; cdecl; external 'Reader.dll';
```

As it is not clear in the DLL's description which calling convention the DLL is actually using.  I suspect `cdecl`.

Comment: Remy , i corrected the declaration , but the result is the same. 
I think that stdcall is the correct calling convention. because use of cdecl , causes a error.

Comment: Remy, I have marked your answer as correct. Thank you